# window.location = "location.html";

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Essentially, I am trying to get my web page to redirect upon successful login. I have the successful login working, it doesn't redirect to the new page afterwards. It refreshes the current page it is on.

The form I am using to take the user input.

```
<!-- Login Details -->
  <form name = "loginForm" onsubmit = "validate(this);">
    <p> 
        <label for = "username"> Username: </label> 
        <input type = "text" id = "username" name = "user"/> 
    </p>

    <p> <label for = "password"> Password: </label> 
        <input type = "password" id = "password" name = "pass" required/>
    </p>

    <p class = "submit"> 
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/> 
    </p>
</form>
```

And now for the JavaScript side of it;

```
var user = form.user.value;
var pass = form.pass.value;
var valid = false;

var userArray = ["admin", "kevin", "mark", "paul", "conor"];        // ("admin1", "admin2", "admin3") As many as you like - no comma after final entry.
var passArray = ["pass", "pass1", "pass2", "pass3", "pass4"];   // ("Password1", "Password2", "Password3") the corresponding passwords;

for (var i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) 
{
    if ((user == userArray[i]) && (pass == passArray[i])) 
    {
        valid = true;
        //alert("Login was successful");
        break;
    }
}

if (valid == true)
{
    alert ("Login was successful");
    window.location = 'mainmenu.html';
    return false;
}
```

I have tried the new location by using both double and single quotes. Neither is working. Appreciate the help :)

Comment: Protip: use `===` it's better practice. Is your alert coming up? The condition might not be passing, which means your if statement could be wrong.

Comment: Submitting a form reloads the page, unless you call `event.preventDefault()` in the submit handler.

Comment: Also, you might be aware of this, but if the JavaScript runs in the client (i.e a web browser), there is nothing preventing someone from looking at the source code and seeing all of the passwords, plus the URL of the page the browser is redirected to after login.

Comment: The alert is still coming up. Just refreshes the form on screen when submit is clicked.

Comment: Oh I know of the security issue with hardcoding the usernames and passwords. This is a college project so the real thing will never be online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are submitting the form. You haven't specified an action, so it submits to the current page. This happens before the `location` assignment has any effect.

With your current approach, to fix it `return false` from `onsubmit` (i.e. the function that *calls* `validate`) so the the normal behaviour of the form submission is canceled.

---

That said:

- Putting all your authentication information on the client is entirely insecure and you should never do it.
- Intrinsic event attributes like `onsubmit` are how we did JS event binding in the 90's. We now have [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) (see also [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)).

Comment: Thought I was returning false with the last line in the if statement? Not gonna lie, we just started Javascript and I still don't know as much about it as I would like.

Comment: @BudgieBr0phy — You are but that's the `validate` function not the `onsubmit` function. The `onsubmit` function is the one with the call to `validate` in it.

Comment: How do I go about returning false on from the onSubmit function?

Comment: You put `return false` after the call to `validate` (or you return the return value of `validate` and return false from that function too)

Comment: Got it! Used onsubmit = "return validate(this)" Thanks for the help @Quentin

Answer (score -1):

From Mozilla Developer Network:

> The Window.location read-only property returns a Location object with
>   information about the current location of the document.

And:

> Whenever a new value is assigned to the location object, a document
>   will be loaded using the URL as if location.assign() had been called
>   with the modified URL. Note that security settings, like CORS, may
>   prevent this to effectively happen.
>
> ```
> location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org"); // or
> location = "http://www.mozilla.org";
> ```

It's example 1 on here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location